# Skip leading whitespaces but not the newline C++ istreams

Tags: c++, char, whitespace, delimiter, istream

I am trying to remove leading whitespace and store the characters after the whitespace. I don't want the newline to be considered

This is a file that I am reading from:

```
Map: Out of planet
Player:    Max
```

My expected result and what I am looking for should be

```
cout << kill.killMap << endl; 
Out of planet    // NOTICE THERE IS NO WHITESPACE
cout << kill.player << endl;   
Max             // NOTICE THERE IS NO WHITESPACE
```

If the file looks like this...

```
Map: 
Player:    Max
```

Nothing should be stored in the `map` variable and `player` variable.

Although the ws function removes whitespace from the stream, I don't think it does the same with char arrays. Would really appreciate it if someone could tell me a way of getting ws to work or just simply an efficient way of removing the whitespace

This is what I am getting:

```
cout << kill.killMap << endl; 
  Out of planet  //THERE IS WHITESPACE
cout << kill.player << endl;   
      Max  //THERE IS WHITESPACE
```

Is there a way of doing this without using C++ strings or Vectors. I intend on using C Style strings

THIS IS MY EDITED CODE, HOWEVER IT DOESN'T WORK IF THERE ARE VALID CHARACTERS AFTER THE DELIMITER `:`... WOULD REALLY APPRECIATE IT IF SOMEONE COULD FIX MY CODE, WOULD MEAN A LOT TO ME.

```
istreams.get(characters, 50, ':');
istreams.get(c);
istreams.getline(kill.killMap, 35);
while ((is.get(c) != "\n") && (is.get(c) != '\0') )
{
    is >> ws;
}
is.getline(kill.killMap, DATA_FILE_SIZE);
if(kill.killMap[0] = '\0)
{ 
   cout << "Error;
   break;
}
istreams >> ws;

istreams.get(characters, 50, ':');
istreams.get(c);
while ((is.get(c) != "\n") && (is.get(c) != '\0') )
{
    is >> ws;
}
istreams.getline(kill.player, 35);
if(kill.player[0] = '\0)
{ 
   cout << "Error;
   break;
}
```

Comment: *"I intend on using C Style strings"* -- Please note that `std::string` exists for a reason. Managing memory manually is simple in theory but is hard to get right in practice, and there is `c_str()` in the event that you need a C-style string for interoperability.

Comment: `std::ws` has nothing to do with character arrays. All it does is discard leading whitespace so that the next character is either a valid character or EOF.

Comment: `is.get(c) != "\n"` is always going to be true unless you have the oddest memory layout imaginable. `"\n"` is a `char(&)[2]`; pretty sure you want `'\n'` instead. That code shouldn't even compile, as at-best you're comparing `char` to `char *`, which are clearly not compatible types.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
void eatwhites(istream& stream)
{
  const string skip=" \t";//put here all wanted skip chars (here i put only SPACE and TAB
  while(string::npos != skip.find(stream.peek())){ //if next char in stream exist in skip string 
    stream.ignore();//then ignore it (1 character).
  }
}
```

*EDIT*

Here is how i tested it and it works for me:

note you still have to trim the string after you read it, means put the `'\0'` after the last non white character.

if there is a problem you can tell what input it was and what have you got.

```
int main()
{ 
    string s1,s2;
    eatwhites(cin);
    getline(cin,s1, ':');//read until ":"
    eatwhites(cin);
    getline(cin,s2); //read until "\n"
    cout<<"'"<<s1<<"':'"<<s2<<"'"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

inputs I've tried:

- [SPACE] 123:[SPACE] 456 gives: '123':'456'
- [SPACE] 123:[SPACE]     gives: '123':''

**EDIT2:**

With `char` array it can be used just the same, like this:

```
#define MAX_FIELD 128
int main()
{ 
    char s1[MAX_FIELD],s2[MAX_FIELD];
    eatwhites(cin);
    cin.getline(s1, MAX_FIELD, ':');
    eatwhites(cin);
    cin.getline(s2, MAX_FIELD);
    cout<<"'"<<s1<<"':'"<<s2<<"'"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Same results for same input.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my code and it works if there is nothing after the delimiter `:`. However, if there is something after the `:` delimiter, it does not store the values after the delimiter

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/skipws/ 

This might also be useful for you.

Comment: @SHR, so if there is nothing after the `:` delimiter it will not store anything? I don't like using string, could you please give a char version if possible or help me modify my code please

Comment: @SamThers [Here's an example that works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9daf91969c09b1c)

Comment: @0x499602D2, thanks, but is there a way of writing `eatwhites` using `char arrays`. I don't want to use string.

Comment: @SHR, is there a way of writing `eatwhites` method using `char arrays` instead of `string`??

Comment: @0x499602D2, thanks, is there a way of incorporating it into my method in the OP. I am already using a `istream` but it is the `while ((is.get(c) != "\n") && (is.get(c) != '\0') )` line where I am going wrong

Comment: @SamThers I'm not understanding why you can't just use my example and change the relevant parts...

Comment: `((is.get(c) != "\n") && (is.get(c) != '\0') )` read 2 chars from the file. that whats wrong. just use `getline` as in my test.

Comment: @SamThers What do you mean how to incorporate it into your code? I just gave you the code to use.